# socket.io client connects to but cannot communicate with netty-socket.io server

Tags: java, sockets, websocket

**Server:**

```java
public class SocketServer {

    private final SocketIOServer socketIOServer;

    public SocketServer() {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.setHostname("localhost");
        config.setPort(9092);

        this.socketIOServer = new SocketIOServer(config);

        socketIOServer.addConnectListener(client -> {
            client.sendEvent("EVENT_CONNECT");
        });

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            socketIOServer.stop();
            System.out.println("Socket server stopped");
        }));

        this.startSocket();
    }

    public void startSocket() {
        socketIOServer.start();
    }

    public void addEventListener(String name, Event event) {
        socketIOServer.addEventListener(name, String.class, event::run);
    }

}
```

**Client:**

```java
public class ConnectionHandler {

    private final Socket socket;

    public ConnectionHandler() throws URISyntaxException {
        this.socket = IO.socket("http://localhost:9092", IO.Options.builder()
                .setTransports(new String[] {"websocket"})
                .setUpgrade(false)
                .setReconnection(true).build());
    }

    public void registerEventListener(String name, Event method) {
        socket.on(name, method::run);
    }

    public void startSocket() {
        socket.open();
    }

    public Socket getSocket() {
        return socket;
    }

}
```

i am 100% certain it is not an issue with my events system, it is something that has to do with the server/library i am using. this client code works perfectly fine with a nodejs socket.io server but when i move it to this server it causes those issues. as i said in the title a connection is recieved but there is nothing communicated between both the sockets

the client is running [socket.io-client 2.1.0](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java)
the server is running [netty-socketio 1.7.23](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio)

if anyone has any better recommendations for libraries to use other than netty-socket.io that also works